# Red Hat 7.4: How to inject kickstart file into USB media for UEFI-only system?

Tags: rhel, uefi, kickstart

I am trying to build an installation image (to be transferred to USB media) for Red Hat Linux 7.4 with a custom kickstart file, and the corresponding `ks=` argument added to grub, but and can't figure out how to do it.

Here are the approaches I have tried:

```
dd if=rhel-server-7.4-x86_64-dvd.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

This builds the a bootable USB stick, but of course without the kickstart file.

Next, I copied the content of the ISO to a temporary file, added my `ks.cfg` and modified the grub configuration, and then used `genisoimage` to rebuild a new image.

```
genisoimage \
  -untranslated-filenames \
  -rational-rock \
  -v \
  -translation-table \
  -input-charset "default" \
  -J \
  -joliet-long \
  $VOLLABELARGS 
  -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
  -c isolinux/boot.cat \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -boot-load-size 4 \
  -boot-info-table \
  -eltorito-alt-boot \
  -efi-boot images/efiboot.img \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -o $THISDIR/$VOLLABEL.iso \
```

This is based on Red Hat's own instructions for RHEL 6 - I am, of course, using RHEL 7. This works for BIOS booting, but when I try it on the UEFI system, the resulting image is rejected as "not compatible".

The resulting image is also noticeably larger than the original RHEL ISO.

Examining it with `xorriso` shows that it is also substantially different from the original. `isohybrid` helps some, but not enough to make the image bootable.

The output of `xorriso -report` on Red Hat's ISO:

```
xorriso -indev rhel-server-7.4-x86_64-dvd.iso -report_el_torito cmd
-volid 'RHEL-7.4 Server.x86_64'
-volume_date uuid '2017071101014600'
-boot_image isolinux system_area=--interval:imported_iso:0s-15s:zero_mbrpt,zero_gpt:'rhel-server-7.4-x86_64-boot.iso'
-boot_image any partition_cyl_align=on
-boot_image any partition_offset=0
-boot_image any partition_hd_cyl=64
-boot_image any partition_sec_hd=32
-boot_image any iso_mbr_part_type=0x00
-boot_image any cat_path='/isolinux/boot.cat'
-boot_image isolinux bin_path='/isolinux/isolinux.bin'
-boot_image any platform_id=0x00
-boot_image any emul_type=no_emulation
-boot_image any load_size=2048
-boot_image any boot_info_table=on
-boot_image any next
-boot_image any efi_path='/images/efiboot.img'
-boot_image any platform_id=0xef
-boot_image any emul_type=no_emulation
-boot_image any load_size=9211904
-boot_image isolinux partition_entry=gpt_basdat
```

And the output of `xorriso` on my image:

```
xorriso -indev myimage.iso -report_el_torito cmd
-volid '"MYIMAGE"'
-volume_date uuid '2018011923504500'
-boot_image isolinux system_area=--interval:imported_iso:0s-15s:zero_mbrpt:'MYIMAGE.iso'
-boot_image any partition_cyl_align=on
-boot_image any partition_offset=0
-boot_image any partition_hd_cyl=64
-boot_image any partition_sec_hd=32
-boot_image any iso_mbr_part_type=0x17
-boot_image any cat_path='/isolinux/boot.cat'
-boot_image isolinux bin_path='/isolinux/isolinux.bin'
-boot_image any platform_id=0x00
-boot_image any emul_type=no_emulation
-boot_image any load_size=2048
-boot_image any boot_info_table=on
-boot_image any next
-boot_image any efi_path='/images/efiboot.img'
-boot_image any platform_id=0xef
-boot_image any emul_type=no_emulation
-boot_image any load_size=9211904
```

Comparing these two, Red Hat has a few GPT-related entries that my image is missing.

Other approaches I have looked at but am not even sure if I'm going off in the wrong direction with those.

- Using lorax/livemedia-creator. I find the instructions quite confusing. It appears to be used to build a live image, but I can't figure out how to invoke Anaconda.
- Format the USB stick as a standard three-partition hard drive. I can't figure out how to make this bootable, though.

What is the best/easiest way to accomplish what I want?

My requirements:

- Must be Linux command line; I want to script this process.
- Should generate an image file, I don't want to write directly to my USB script if I can avoid it.
- Should be able to run as non-root user.

The image file does not need to support CD/DVD booting.

Comment: For option #2, have you looked at the `man` page for `grub2-install`? (https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-grub2-install/) There's an option: `--efi-directory=DIR` that might be of use to you. I honestly think the route of installing grub on one partition and putting together a grub config is the easiest route when it comes to booting off USBs. I haven't had much luck finding a tool to do it for me.

Comment: Never use `genisoimage`, it is full of well known bugs and unmaintained by the publishers. Better use the original software `mkisofs` that has no known bugs and is maintained.

Comment: @schily That's a tough call to make in this case, actually. genisoimage is in the official RedHat repository, so even if it isn't supported by the authors, it is supported by RH. xorriso comes from the EPEL repository. Generally speaking, while EPEL is very good, in my experience the quality isn't up to RedHat's quality. It has been a while since I did this, but IIRC, mkisofs was not an option; I think it may have been missing a few features critical for this project.

Comment: Please note that genisoimage has aprox. 50 bugs that are unfixed since 12 years. Genisoimage must be seen as completely unsupported by RH. In special as the well known bugs result in defects in the file system image that is created. BTW: mkisofs implements twice as many features than genisoimage, do you really believe mkisofs in inferior? Check: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man8/mkisofs.8.html

Comment: Looking a bit deeper into this: mkisofs is simply not available for RedHat, neither in the official repos nor in EPEL. I avoid other sources of software, simply to keep my sanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simpler approach now that would likely work well with both RHEL/CentOS and Fedora ISOs -- since it's part of the `lorax` project that RHEL and Fedora uses to build its ISOs in the first place, [mkksiso](https://github.com/weldr/lorax/blob/master/docs/mkksiso.rst). I've only tested it on Fedora 32 though.

There's a bug I discovered when testing it; if the source ISO is bootable on both UEFI and Macs, the new ISO is only bootable on Macs and on legacy BIOS systems. Fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/weldr/lorax/pull/1047) but it's not released yet, but `mkksiso` is a simple Python script that you can just download separately if the rest of `lorax` is installed.

Injecting a kickstart is now as simple as:

```
sudo dnf install lorax
wget -cN https://raw.githubusercontent.com/weldr/lorax/master/src/sbin/mkksiso
chmod +x mkksiso
sudo ./mkksiso -V MyNewVolumeID path/to/kickstart path/to/orig.iso path/to/
```

see e.g. https://github.com/michel-slm/luks-kickstarts/blob/master/rebuild.sh

Comment: Thank you! I remember looking at lorax back then but couldn't quite figure it out. With your tip, I may get it to work. That said, I'm not really using this approach any more; I'm now using a boot ISO from a Satellite Server.

Answer (score 3):

I now have completed the process, thanks to @[Thomas Schmitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419040/266568)'s invaluable tip.

Here is the complete process.

**Overview**

You must modify three files on the original Red Hat DVD:

- `isolinux/isolinux.cfg`
- `EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg`
- `images/efiboot.img`

Decide on a volume label that you want to use. The volume label should be shorter than 14 characters.

Then use `genisoimage` to build the new ISO with that volume label, use `isohybrid --uefi` to make it UEFI compatible, and use `implantisomd5` to update the correct checksum

**Step-by-Step**

I have scripted this, but the script is very specific to our situation, so no point in posting it.

- Mount the original Red Hat DVD using `fuseiso`.
- Set an environment variable `VOLUMELABEL` to your chosen volume label.
- Copy the three files you need to modify to another location.

Edit the `isolinux.cfg` file. This file will be used for BIOS booting.

- Edit the `isolinux.cfg` file, adding the argument to the first two lines that start with `append`: `ks=hd:LABEL=$VOLUMELABEL:/ks.cfg`.
- Update the `inst.stage2` argument everywhere you find it (probably four places) to read: `inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=$VOLUMELABEL`.
- You may also want to remove the `menu default` entry so your image defaults to `Install` instead of `Test & Install`.

Edit the `grub.cfg` file. This file will be used for EFI booting. Note that this file (and everything in `EFI/BOOT`) will exist twice: once on the regular DVD image, and also inside the `efiboot.img` file.

- Add the same argument to the first two lines that start with `linuxefi`.
- Update the `inst.stage2` argument everywhere you find it (probably four places) to read: `inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=$VOLUMELABEL`.
- IMPORTANT AND EASY TO OVERLOOK: Also edit the line that starts with `search` in `grub.cfg`.

Edit the `efiboot.img` file. This will actually be booted by EFI.

- Mount your copy of the `efiboot.img` file. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to do this with `fusermount`, so you have to be root to do this.
- Copy the modified `grub.cfg` into the `efiboot.img` file under `EFI/BOOT`
- Umount your copy of the `efiboot.img` file.

Now you can generate the ISO image.

The arguments to `genisoimage` are position-sensitive. Key points: I base the image on the original mounted ISO file (mounted as `$TMPDIR`), then use `-m` to exclude the three modified files, and use graft points to insert the modifications, as well as the kickstart file, into the image. In my image, I also removed the directory addons.

```
genisoimage \
  -untranslated-filenames \
  -graft-points \
  -rational-rock \
  -v \
  -translation-table \
  -input-charset "default" \
  -J \
  -joliet-long \
  -V $VOLLABEL -A $VOLLABEL -volset $VOLLABEL \
  -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
  -c isolinux/boot.cat \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -boot-load-size 4 \
  -boot-info-table \
  -eltorito-alt-boot \
  -efi-boot images/efiboot.img \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -quiet \
  -o $THISDIR/$VOLLABEL.iso \
  -m $TMPDIR/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg \
  -m $TMPDIR/isolinux/isolinux.cfg \
  -m $TMPDIR/images/efiboot.img \
  -m addons \
  $TMPDIR \
  EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg=$TMPGRAFT/grub.cfg \
  isolinux/isolinux.cfg=$TMPGRAFT/isolinux.cfg \
  images/efiboot.img=$TMPGRAFT/efiboot.img \
  $KICKSTARTFILE=$KICKSTARTDIR/$KICKSTARTFILE
```

Then use `isohybrid --uefi` and `implantisomd5`:

```
isohybrid --uefi $THISDIR/$VOLUMELABEL.iso
implantisomd5 $THISDIR/$VOLUMELABEL.iso
```

Answer (score 2):

The decisive advantage of original over genisoimage remake is probably
in the line

```
-boot_image isolinux partition_entry=gpt_basdat
```

genisoimage cannot make partition tables for EFI.
(Inspect both ISOs by "/sbin/fdisk -l" to see the difference.)
You actually need the MBR partition of type 0xef. But tradition is to
also add an invalid and thus useless GPT.

One way to get the partition tables would be to run after genisoimage

```
isohybrid --uefi $THISDIR/$VOLLABEL.iso
```

The program stems from SYSLINUX source. One should use the version from
the same source release or git clone from which "isolinux.bin" stems.

Other distros use xorriso's mkisofs emulation with the boot options which
this xorriso command tells:

```
xorriso -indev rhel-server-7.4-x86_64-dvd.iso -report_el_torito as_mkisofs
```

There will be a lengthy addess to option -isohybrid-mbr:

```
--interval:imported_iso:0s-15s:zero_mbrpt,zero_gpt:'rhel-server-7.4-x86_64-boot.iso
```

It tells xorriso to use the first 32 KiB of the original ISO as MBR template
and further System Area. Normally it is SYSLINUX file "isohdpfx.bin", which has
only 432 bytes. You may replace it by "mbr.bin" after copying the first 
432 bytes yourself:

```
dd if=rhel-server-7.4-x86_64-dvd.iso bs=432 count=1 of=mbr.bin
```

Comment: Thank you! I had used isohybrid, but not the --uefi switch. And that did indeed do the trick, at least as far as it goes. Grub comes up, but then complains that it can't find vmlinuz. That's just standard EFI partition manipulation, though.

Comment: After posting my question, I also found this (RedHat login required): https://access.redhat.com/solutions/60959 . RedHat says that building your own ISO is not supported, but provides some helpful tips anyway.

Comment: Just for the records: The RedHat/Fedora ISOs get rebuild correctly during
my xorriso regression tests. (Not in reach for xorriso are the two-headed
SuSE FrankenISOs, the boot equipment of most BSD ISOs, and the UDFs by
Microsoft.)

Comment: For an EFI boot, you do not need an EFI partition table and the better original software `mkisofs` supports EFI boot. See: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man8/mkisofs.8.html

Answer (score 2):

Based on answers from [Thomas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419040/69010) and [Kevin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420491/69010) I managed to get a working procedure based on `xorriso`, which is available from EPEL. My goals were similar to Kevin's:

- Use a stock RHEL 7 installation media
- Implant a kickstart and configuration scripts into the resulting image
- Select the kickstart automatically for installation
- Produce an image compatible with UEFI boot
- Make the procedure scripted

Tested successfully with RHEL 7.5 and 7.6.

### Step by step procedure

1. Have `xorriso` installed from EPEL.
2. Have RHEL 7 installation DVD downloaded in `$ISO_SRC`.
3. Have your kickstart (`ks.cfg`) and scripts ready in `$SCRIPTS`.
4. Extract files, which need to be customized, from ISO into `$FILES`:

   - `isolinux/isolinux.cfg`
   - `EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg`
   - `images/efiboot.img`
5. Modify the `*.cfg` boot configuration files in `$FILES`:

   Note: I do not modify the disc label (or volume ID) intentionally. It is space sensitive (potentially any special characters) and I found it easier to reuse it instead of replacing.

   - add kickstart parameter to boot command

     `'(.*)(hd:LABEL=\S+)(.*)'` → `'\1\2 inst.ks=\2:/$SCRIPTS/ks.cfg\3'`
   - set default boot menu for legacy boot in `isolinux.cfg`

     `'^\s*menu default\s*\n'` → `''`
   - set default boot menu for UEFI boot in `grub.cfg`

     `'set default=.*'` → `'set default="0"'`
6. Modify the UEFI boot image `images/efiboot.img` in `$FILES`:

   - mount it in a temporary directory
   - copy the UEFI boot menu `$FILES/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg` into it
   - unmount
7. Build your customized image:

   ```
   xorriso \
     -indev "$ISO_SRC" \
     -map "$SCRIPTS" /"$SCRIPTS" \
     -map "$FILES" / \
     -boot_image any replay \
     -outdev "$ISO_DST"
   ```

   The command copies contents of the source ISO image `$ISO_SRC`, merges local directories' contents and replays all boot settings from the source into the destination image `$ISO_DST`. No further steps are required.

### Note on `geniso` method

I had hard time with following the `geniso` method as described by [Kevin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420491/69010). I managed to produce the output ISO image, however, `geniso` was complaining about not being able to modify the `isolinux.bin` image, hence I had to extract it too. This is not mentioned in the procedure.

I faced the wall on enabling the UEFI boot with `isohybrid`. It returned an error I did not find a workaround for:

```
$ isohybrid --uefi rhel-custom.iso
isohybrid: rhel-custom.iso: boot loader does not have an isolinux.bin hybrid 
signature. Note that isolinux-debug .bin does not support hybrid booting
```

### Ansible role

I did create an Ansible role, which performs the task: [build_boot_iso](https://galaxy.ansible.com/gadamiak/build_boot_iso).

Comment: Thank you for reporting your experience! I wonder why you were having problems with isolinux.bin. I have used my method with 7.5, as well, and didn't need to copy isolinux.bin anywhere else. Did you use the -b isolinux/isolinux.bin argument ? The problem with isohybrid seems like it is somehow related to the isolinux.bin issue. Interesting idea to use -indev and -outdev with xorriso; that seems much simpler than my method.

Comment: I did follow your instructions almost literally (needed to decrypt your setup from variables, though), so yes, there were all the switches. I thought it might be related to unmatching `isolinux.bin` stem. However, searching around I found info it shouldn't matter if your system is decent enough. I'm using a patched RHEL 7 with 7.5 media, which might possibly be a bit ahead of the ISO. Anyway, the `xorriso` method works like a charm and is much more straightforward.

Comment: I did publish an ansible role, which performs the task of creating a boot ISO based on my instructions. The link is in the answer body.

Comment: @gadamiak Have you tried livecd-creator?

Comment: For some reason the Ansible role is not properly linked; here it is: https://github.com/gadamiak/build_boot_iso/

Comment: Thanks for catching @michel-slm. It was a bad reference in my Markdown. It's corrected now.

Comment: @gadamiak what do you think of the ordering change suggested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/556992/9818 ? I tried it both ways and it seems to work the same

Comment: @michel-slm it worked for me with the order of arguments I described. I can't recall now whether I have checked the different order. If both versions work for you equally, then fine. Enjoy :)

Comment: @gadamiak it's weird - I tried either way, and both work on one laptop (a Dell Precision 5540) but would boot like a normal installer (as if the kickstart does not exist) on another (a Dell XPS 13). This is with the Fedora 32 ISO though, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for a way to natively use `xorriso` with no other dependencies and [gadamiak's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495799/369009) answer is spot on. The only discrepancy is Step 7, which should reflect:

```
xorriso \
  -indev "$ISO_SRC" \
  -boot_image any replay \
  -map "$SCRIPTS" /"$SCRIPTS" \
  -map "$FILES" / \
  -outdev "$ISO_DST"
```

Order matters, so if `-boot_image any replay` is specified after `-map`, the mapped directories are overwritten with the default ISO content.

[Here is a link to my GitHub repository](https://github.com/Fauxsys/Erratum/blob/master/unattended.sh) which contains a bash script that injects a kickstart file into USB media for UEFI-only system.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Please suggest this as an edit on gadamiak’s answer.

Comment: I spent hours using the order in the top rated answer, only to make this --boot_image order change to solve the problem. The top answer should be modified to at least note this as a possibility.